# Method for adding a new object to a list if the new object it doesn't exist in the list already

Tags: c#, list, methods

AddFragment: Adds a sound-fragment to the list, if allowed. If there does not already
exist a sound fragment in the list with identy-number equal to idNr, a new soundfragment
is created (according to the values of the parameters) and added to the list
and the value true is returned in this situation. However, if there does already exist a
sound fragment in the list with identy-number equal to idNr, the method returns false.

```
public bool  AddFragment (int _idNr, String _fileName, string _tile, int _duration)
    {
        foreach (SoundFragment fs3 in Fragments)
        {
            if (fs3.IdNr == __Idr ) ;

            else
            {
                foreach (SoundFragment fs4 in Fragments)
                {
                    if (fs4.IdNr != __Idr)
                    {
                        Fragments.Add(new SoundFragment(_idNr, _fileName, _tile, _duration));
                    }
                    return true;
                }

            }
        return false;
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense as you have an empty `if` block. Perhaps you should be looking at using a `Dictionary` here?

Comment: @DavidG: The empty `if` makes sense, although it is a little wonky. That is `if (x); else { ... }` is the same as `if (!x) { ... }`

Comment: @JimMischel Haha yes. But I meant "doesn't make sense" as in "not sensible" rather than it not compiling. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [IEnumerable.Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) extension to look into your collection

```
public bool  AddFragment (int _idNr, String _fileName, string _tile, int _duration)
{
    bool added = false;
    if(!Fragments.Any( x => x.IdNr == _idr))
    {
       Fragments.Add(new SoundFragment(_idNr, _fileName, _tile, _duration));
       added = true;
    }
    return added;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whereas I would suggest you use the LINQ solution posted previously, the non-LINQ solution is:

```
public bool  AddFragment (int _idNr, String _fileName, string _tile, int _duration)
{
    // Scan the list, looking for an existing fragment with this id number.
    foreach (SoundFragment fs3 in Fragments)
    {
        if (fs3.IdNr == _idNr)
        {
            // found a matching fragment, so don't need to add.
            return false;
        }
    }
    // No matching fragment found. Add a new one.
    Fragments.Add(new SoundFragment(....));
    return true;
}
```